# Interlocked API between Windows CE 5 and 6

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, windows-ce

I'm currently porting a VS2005 C++ application from CE5 to CE6 and I'm experiencing severe performance problems. This goes so far that a single HTTP request retrieving dynamic content takes 40ms on CE5 and 350ms on CE6. These values used to be worse due to a bunch of inefficiencies that I already cleaned up, improving performance on both systems, but at the moment I'm stuck at that latency. For the record, both tests are made on the same machine and the webserver is not the one supplied with CE but a custom one implemented in C++. Note also that the problem is not the network IO, CE6 even outperforms CE5 on the same machine when serving static files, but it's the dynamic content handling.

While trying to figure out why the program performs so badly, I stumbled across something that puzzled me: Under CE5, the Interlocked* API for x86 use neither the compiler intrinsics nor real function calls but inline assembly code. This code has a comment saying that the intrinsic includes lock prefixes that are only required for multi-processor systems and that slow down code running on just a single core like CE5. On CE6, these functions are implemented using the compiler intrinsics including the lock prefix. Since these functions are used by e.g. Boost and STLport, both of which are used inside the webserver, I was wondering if those could be the culprit.

Another thing I noticed was that some string parsing functions take extremely long. Worse, it seems that calling the same function a second time after the first time takes less time, so it seems as if some kind of caching was going on. Since this is a short (<1kB) string received via TCP that is parsed in memory, I can't imagine which cache could be responsible for that. The only cache could be the instruction cache, but the program is not larger than the CE5 version and if the code was running from uncached memory it would not show these caching effects.

TLDR - Questions:

- Is CE6 capable of handling multiple processors at all?
- Is there an easy way to tell the compiler that it should omit the lock prefix? My current approach to achieve that is to simply copy the inline assembly from the CE5 SDK, but that's beyond ugly.
- I'd also appreciate any other suggestions what to look at or what to try. Many thanks in advance!

**Summary** There is no problem that depends on the executable, let alone on the Interlocked API. Running the same executable proved that. However, running on a different machine with a different platform setup made a difference. We're now back to Platform Builder, trying to figure out the differences between the two platforms.

Comment: When you strip out the lock, does it change performance characteristics of your app? If you want some more suggestions, I suggest profiling! According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE) (perhaps not the most reliable source I know) SMP support was added in CE7

Comment: Is there a way to strip out these locks after compiling? Compiling the executable and DLLs takes around two hours and I'd hesitate to hack around in the SDK headers.

Comment: I thought you said you already had stripped them out. That's what you said in your second bullet.

Comment: Sorry for this misunderstanding. I currently don't see any other way except the one described, but I haven't fully tried that yet.

Comment: We can't run your program and so have no idea where the performance bottleneck is. You on the other hand can identify the bottleneck.

Comment: What CPU architecture? Ce on x86? Wow really?

Comment: @Warren: why is that "wow?"  CE's been running on x86 since the very early days, and almost all reference code from Microsoft is on the x86.

Comment: Warren, ctacke: The real WTF is that we're moving from an obsolete & buried system to a mostly obsolete system. Don't ask.

Comment: David: Obviously nobody here can run this specific program. I'm rather looking for general advise from previous experiences with porting to CE6.

Comment: If I was working where you were, and you had PC-class embedded hardware, headless or not, with ethernet, I would be pushing for abandoning CE and moving to Linux. I have implemented Linux, Pharlap, CE, ECOS, µC/OS, QNX, and Windows Embedded, and Linux is the only one I'd do again. The others... Shudder.

Comment: Short update: Instead of hacking the CE6 build to not include the multiprocessor lock prefix, we ran the same binaries as those compiled for CE5 (with some hardware-specific stuff removed). Those CE5 binaries on CE6 also performed badly, so the lock prefix doesn't impose a significant overhead on our app.

Comment: Why actually you are moving co CE6? If your app compiles with CE5 it will work on CE6 without the need for recompilation. Profiling is the only option for You, you might also write some benchmarks to verify if this device is slow on memory, SD card access etc. And verify results with WCE5 device. I use to use q-bench application for that. Are you running your application from internal memory on device or maybe from SD card?

Comment: The target machine has reached end of production and the newer one is not supported by CE5, hence the move is inevitable. Of course, trying to pin the slowness on a specific part (NIC, CF-Card, CPU) was the first approach, but didn't yield any insight. The current state is what I added as summary above, i.e. that it seems to the the particular CE6 configuration (as opposed to the compiler or CE6 in general) that causes problems.

Answer (score 2):

1. No. WEC7 is required for SMP support. Most likely in CE6 the OEM has disabled the other cores.
2. None that I am aware of.
3. Either use the [performance profiling tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee480251%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx) or instrument your code with timing calls to narrow down where things are taking too long.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and the link! I was aware of kernel-tracker and I'll take a look at the other supplied tools today. Concerning timing calls, I'm already doing that, but the results are kind-of elusive and I fail to understand the behaviour, see the description concerning "caching" above.

Comment: I've no idea why string parsing functions would take longer under CE5 than CE6. One other possibility, if your CE 5 product was running in ALLKMODE, you could see some performance hits because CE6 doesn't support that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee483028(v=winembedded.60).aspx

Comment: Indeed, we're directly accessing the PCI bus under CE5, so we switched off the "proper" kernel/userspace separation. I'll try switching that back on for CE5 to see if it makes the difference.

Comment: Just for the record, adding the separation between kernel and userspace didn't have any noticeable effect.

Comment: Some more updates: I have seen fluctuations between the different runs of the same HTTP request, skipping back and forth between a reasonable latency and one that is 400% too high. My current search goes the direction of lock convoys, which could explain this behaviour. Looking into changes between CE5 and CE6 that could explain this...

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the reason for the performance behaviour, it's simply paging. CE6 has a pool manager (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ce_base/archive/2008/01/19/paging-and-the-windows-ce-paging-pool.aspx) which handles paging out unused mapped DLLs and EXEs. When the amount of mapped binaries exceeds a certain size, it starts (with low priority) to page out memory. The limit when it starts paging out is just 3MiB by default, which is rather low for current applications. Also, the cache is not an LRU cache but simply discarding the pages in the order they were loaded.

It turns out that our system exceeded this limit, which causes the paging to begin. Due to the algorithm used, it will always throw out used ones that will then have to be paged in again. The code that serves static files is small, so this wasn't affected as much by this limit. The code that serves dynamic pages is much larger though, so it wreaks havoc on the overall system with IO. This also explains why the problem couldn't be attributed to a specific piece of code, it wasn't the code itself but loading it.

I have detected this via IOCTL_HAL_GET_POOL_PARAMETERS, which gave me the relevant configuration parameters, current state, how often the pageout-thread ran and for how long (although the latter is only the time it took to swap out pages). I should be able to find the resulting page faults in the kernel tracker, too, now that I know what I'm looking for. I could also observe that the activity LED on the CF card adapter now lights up when first loading a file, but not on subsequent requests, where it is taken from cache. This used to always cause the LED to flash on dynamic pages.

The simple solution is to increase the limit for the pool manager, so it doesn't start throwing out things. This can be done easily in config.bib by patching kernel.dll with the according values. Alternatively, reducing the executable size would help, but that's not so easy.